# Is there an offline RSS Reader for Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I'm looking for an offline RSS reader, which also downloads images embedded into the feed.
I've tried (and liked) NetNewsWire (and the Lite Version of it), but it does not seem to store embedded images for offline viewing, which is a must for me.
I've no other requirements except this, so it doesn't matter if it syncs to Google Reader or to iOS.

Does anybody know of an application that can actually accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Reeder](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/reeder/id439845554?mt=12) supports offline reading of your RSS feed. It will fetch and cache a configurable amount of feed history for you to peruse while you aren't connected to the web. And it'll look darn good while doing it. (Can you tell I'm a fan?)

Comment: I've actually bought it just now, but it looks as if it does not download the images either. Just the feeds themselves. But yes, it looks awesome. edit: Actually it stores already fetched images until you switch to another feed, then deletes them, which is pretty useless.

Comment: Preferences -> Syncing tab -> Make sure 'Download read items' is checked. I believe that'll save your images after you've switched feeds.

Comment: Also, consider submitting this feedback to the dev. He's a good guy and has been known to turn around features fast if you ask nicely.

Comment: It is checked (it was by default). Also I've actually just written a mail to the support address. It's a nice reader nevertheless and if I have to live with this little pet peeve, I'm fine with that. Would be a really useful feature for me though.

Comment: It looks great and I'd love to use it but the $9.99 price tag puts me off. /cheapskate

Comment: Yeah, I get that. It's worth it thought after having tested it myself. It's pretty similar to NetNewsWire Lite thought (which is free, but without Google Reader Sync). Also I'm marking this as the answer now. It's not the solution I was looking for, but good enough for now.

Comment: @XQYZ - I am tempted, there's no question... It looks the goods and I'm a heavy Google Reader user... hmmm...